# Select command to union specific records from one table with each subset of records from another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables A, B.
I am trying to combine the record from table A with the area = a1 and rmid = 1 with each set(s1,s2,s3) of records from table B where B.pid = A.rmid and A.rmid = 999.
The result should look like table C.

I would welcome any ideas.

```
A                       B                         C
area | rmid | rmset     pid | rmid | setid        area | rmid | setid
--------------------    ----------------          --------------------
a1   | 1    |           999 | 11   | s1           a1   | 1    | s1
a1   | 999  | yes       999 | 12   | s1           a1   | 11   | s1
a2   | 2    |           999 | 13   | s1           a1   | 12   | s1
a2   | 998  | yes       999 | 14   | s2           a1   | 13   | s1      
                        999 | 15   | s2           a1   | 1    | s2
                        999 | 16   | s3           a1   | 14   | s2
                                                  a1   | 15   | s2
                                                  a1   | 1    | s3
                                                  a1   | 16   | s3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one option; sample data in lines #1 - 15, query begins at line #16.

```
SQL> with
  2  a (area, rmid) as
  3    (select 'a1', 1   from dual union all
  4     select 'a1', 999 from dual union all
  5     select 'a2', 2   from dual union all
  6     select 'a2', 998 from dual
  7    ),
  8  b (pid, rmid, setid) as
  9    (select 999, 11, 's1' from dual union all
 10     select 999, 12, 's1' from dual union all
 11     select 999, 13, 's1' from dual union all
 12     select 999, 14, 's2' from dual union all
 13     select 999, 15, 's2' from dual union all
 14     select 999, 16, 's3' from dual
 15    )
```

---

```
 16  select a.area, a.rmid, x.setid
 17  from a cross join (select distinct b.setid from b) x
 18  where a.rmid = 1
 19  union
 20  select a.area, b.rmid, b.setid
 21  from a join b on a.rmid = b.pid
 22  where a.rmid = 999
 23  order by area, setid, rmid;

AREA        RMID SETID
----- ---------- -------
a1             1 s1
a1            11 s1
a1            12 s1
a1            13 s1
a1             1 s2
a1            14 s2
a1            15 s2
a1             1 s3
a1            16 s3

9 rows selected.

SQL>
```